# Ubuntu Server losing network connection

Tags: networking, server, power-management

My issue is simple, yet really complex. I recently installed Ubuntu server on an old stripped down laptop. It's a SAHARA LE1D, 1.4 Intel Celeron m I think. It's an old one, but still good.

The eth0 connection is: (from `lshw -class network`)

```
-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: SiS900 PCI Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
   physical id: 4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 91
   serial: 00:16:36:30:53:ae
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sis900 driverversion=v1.08.10 Apr. 2 2006 duplex=full ip=10.0.0.14 latency=173 link=yes maxlatency=11 mingnt=52 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 ioport:1800(size=256) memory:e4003000-e4003fff memory:30020000-3003ffff
```

The problem is this. The network drops after a while, but only if I have my deluge client running and I am not sshed into the server. The server is serving up two websites and the web-client for deluge. But after starting a torrent, after a while the network drops and I can't ssh into it or see the websites.

If I then press a key on the connected keyboard, the network jumps right back into life. However the server isn't sleeping. It's still definitely on.

I've tried the ping thing, denoted by faulty hardware thinking the network is inactive (which isn't an issue since a torrent is running), and I've tried looking in dmesg and syslog, kern.log too, but nothing that I can make sense of.

Any ideas? I'd really like my server to not disconnect when torrenting, but my bigger worry is if its generally unstable, it may not only be torrents that cause it. It hasn't been up for a long time.

It's running ubuntu Server 32bit 14.04.

Edit 1 : I have concluded that having ssh open changes nothing. It still closes access to the server after some time.

Here's something from dmesg:

```
[   19.662131] type=1400 audit(1398606232.597:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=426 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.662146] type=1400 audit(1398606232.597:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=426 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.662663] type=1400 audit(1398606232.597:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=426 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.664390] type=1400 audit(1398606232.601:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=427 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.664409] type=1400 audit(1398606232.601:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=427 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.664419] type=1400 audit(1398606232.601:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=427 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.665437] type=1400 audit(1398606232.601:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=427 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   24.542312] init: cups main process (621) killed by HUP signal
[   24.542340] init: cups main process ended, respawning
[   26.736358] eth0: Media Link Off
[   31.746038] eth0: Media Link On 100mbps full-duplex
[   33.609808] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (673) terminated with status 1
[   40.667068] init: samba-ad-dc main process (685) terminated with status 1
[   41.165841] init: failsafe main process (492) killed by TERM signal
[   42.033077] audit_printk_skb: 15 callbacks suppressed
[   42.033087] type=1400 audit(1398606254.969:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1018 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   42.033104] type=1400 audit(1398606254.969:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1018 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   42.033115] type=1400 audit(1398606254.969:19): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1018 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   42.034147] type=1400 audit(1398606254.969:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1018 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   42.034157] type=1400 audit(1398606254.969:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1018 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   42.034700] type=1400 audit(1398606254.969:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1018 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   42.371429] type=1400 audit(1398606255.305:23): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=1019 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   42.379703] type=1400 audit(1398606255.313:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1022 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   42.379725] type=1400 audit(1398606255.313:25): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1022 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   42.381050] type=1400 audit(1398606255.317:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1022 comm="apparmor_parser"   
[   52.425610] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   54.735414] audit_printk_skb: 12 callbacks suppressed
[   54.735424] type=1400 audit(1398606267.669:31): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1487 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   54.735591] type=1400 audit(1398606267.669:32): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1487 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   54.737099] type=1400 audit(1398606267.673:33): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1487 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: Seems like a power management issue, set it up so it doesn't go to sleep on inactivity from keyboard etc

Comment: @LinuxDevOps The Server doesn't sleep, It stays active for days, if deluge isn't running. But when I start the torrenting, it dies after a while. Could you tell me how to switch off power management anyway? It'll be a useful test.

Comment: I have disabled the power saving stuff as suggested. This seems to have worked. I'll post final results as an answer later on.

Comment: Setting acpi=off makes the problem go away. The server runs stably, how can I find out what the actual issue is?

Comment: Some more experimentation has made this a whole new issue. I'm going to open a new question with a new description. The laptop is somehow "freezing" to be woken by usb events only. the time on the server is very wrong after its "woken".